# Почему не работает проксирование?

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать проксирование в javascript и не могу понять почему данный код работает

```
let array = [];

array = new Proxy(array, {
  set(target, prop, value) {
    if (typeof value === "number") {
      target[prop] = value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

array.push(1);
```

А этот нет

```
let array = [];

array = new Proxy(array, {
  set(target, prop, value) {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      target[prop] = value;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

array.push("123dsfsdf");
```

выдет ошибку TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'length'

В чем проблема?

Comment: метод `.push` также меняет свойство `length`, которое является числом. В твоем обработчике это не отслеживается и в итоге ошибка, что свойство не может быть изменено

Comment: Не до конца понял суть

Comment: когда что-то куда то пихаете изменяется длина. вызывается length++ который отрезается вашим `=== string`, видимо как-то так

Comment: можете проверить, сделав `typeof value == 'string' || prop == 'length'`

Comment: @teran, Спасибо за ответ, а почему выдаст ошибку когда value === number, если условие правее выполняется? Ведь мы же используем не логическое и

Comment: не ясно о чем речь